# Use registry to see ICMP type settings

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, icmp

I would like to see which ICMP types are allowed / enabled on my system.

I've found [this](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2609/How-to-Enable-PingorICMP-Echo-Request-in-Windows-Server.html) where you can set up your ICMP but is there a possibility to see these settings in registry or to get them through powershell commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Get-NetFirewallRule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/get-netfirewallrule) to enumerate the firewall rules. Use [`Get-NetFirewallPortFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/get-netfirewallportfilter) to get details about what these rules are filtering. Filter the output for ICMP protocol rules, then select the ICMP type.

```
Get-NetFirewallRule -Enabled True -Action Allow |
    Get-NetFirewallPortFilter |
    Where-Object { $_.Protocol -in 'icmpv4', 'icmpv6' } |
    Select-Object -Expand IcmpType -Unique
```

Replace `Allow` with `Block` to enumerate blocking rules.

If `Get-NetFirewallRule` can't find a rule it will throw an error. You can suppress that by adding `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the command.

Note that the `*-NetFirewall*` cmdlets were introduced with Windows Server 2012 and are not available in earlier versions. For those you need to work with the [`netsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd734783%28v%3dws.10%29) command. Use something like this to enumerate firewall rules

```
netsh advfirewall firewall show rule all
```

and parse the output for the relevant information.

Comment: This helps me a lot. Thank you!
Can you also tell me what I should do with `advfirewall` to get the same result like using `netsh firewall show icmpsetting`?

Comment: Like I said, you'd need to parse the output of `netsh advfirewall firewall show rule all`.